# Why is JqueryUI's button slow in IE?

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I've been tracking down a performance problem in one of our javascript app (in IE, to make matter worse) and I was able to track it down to jQueryUI button feature. I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzZ87/4) showing the issue. The problem is 3 parts:

First, the generation of the buttons is extremely slow. The page generates 800 buttons in 5+ seconds under IE8, whereas it takes around 700ms when I disable the button feature. To make it worse, it gets slower and slower for every create/delete cycle. For comparison, in Chrome it takes less than a second (around 600ms) with the button feature and around 50ms without it. That's a 10x slow down for both browser!

Second, deleting/destroying all those button is also slow. I use the `empty()` method on the container to clean all the buttons and that ultimatly calls `destroy` on the button. This operation takes around 5 seconds under IE8 and 500ms in Chrome. Once I remove the jquery button feature, it takes 200ms in IE8 and 30-40ms in Chrome. That's a 20x slow down, worse than generating the button themselves.

Third, it seems that the button feature causes a huge memory leak in IE. Repeatedly creating and deleting the buttons result in the memory usage going up and up, but once again removing the button feature fixes this.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Is this a performance problem in jQueryUI that should be reported or am I hitting a pitfall? Any workarounds?

**Note**: when I say i remove the button feature, it's not that I remove the `<button>` element from the document, it's just that I remove the call to jqueryUI's button function:

```
.button({
   'text': true
})
```

Comment: You've discovered that IE sucks. Welcome to the club. We have pins.

Comment: just press ctrl+F4 and all probs getting solved!

Comment: I knew that IE sucked well before that... problem is, this thing is not an IE related problem. True, it's a hell of a lot slower in IE, but as I noted it's still 10x slower when using buttons in Chrome­.